# Align the top of a View to the bottom of another view in a RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I align a `View`'s top to another `View`'s bottom? I need two views one on top of another. I achieved the right vertical position with a simple `android:layout_below="id_of_the_top_view"`, but I can't manage to align the `View`s horizontally. I would something like `android:layout_alignTopToBottomOf="id_of_the_top_view"`, or in general something that lets me align a `View` center (horizontal or vertical) to another `View` center.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<!-- center picker @ minutes -->
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/npicker_minutes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

<!-- left picker @ hours -->
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/npicker_hours"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/npicker_minutes" />

<!-- right picker @ seconds -->
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/npicker_seconds"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/npicker_minutes" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_minutes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@id/npicker_minutes"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:text="@string/minutes_short" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/npicker_hours"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/tv_minutes"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:text="@string/hours_short" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/npicker_seconds"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/tv_minutes"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:text="@string/seconds_short" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

What I've got is this:
[image]

And what I need to achieve is that the three `TextView`s ("hh", "mm" and "ss"), are placed each one below one of the number pickers, with the horizontal center of the `TextView` aligned to the horizontal center of the `NumberPicker`.

Comment: please post your xml and eloborate using that what you want to achive

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited my question providing as many informations as I could. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to add this lines to your TextViews:

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/npicker_minutes"
android:layout_alignRight="@id/npicker_minutes"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
```

Complete sample of your code:

```
<!-- center picker @ minutes -->

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/npicker_minutes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />

<!-- left picker @ hours -->

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/npicker_hours"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/npicker_minutes" />

<!-- right picker @ seconds -->

<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/npicker_seconds"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/npicker_minutes" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_minutes"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/npicker_minutes"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/npicker_minutes"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/npicker_minutes"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:text="@string/minutes_short" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/npicker_hours"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/npicker_hours"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/npicker_hours"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:text="@string/hours_short" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@id/npicker_seconds"
    android:layout_alignRight="@id/npicker_seconds"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@id/npicker_seconds"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:text="@string/seconds_short" />
```

The alternative way is to use tree LinearLayouts, every with one NumberPicker and one TextView inside.

Comment: Perfect, that was exactly what I was searching for.

Answer (score 5):

in my case i use android:layout_above

```
 <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/layout_bottom"
        >
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following properties to align the first and the third text view:

```
      android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/your_first_number_picker" //your first text view

 android:layout_alignRight="@+id/your_third_number_picker" //your third text view
```

Comment: I tried this way, but the horizontal center of the `TextView`s is not aligned with the horizontal center of the number pickers. They're aligned with the right and left side of the number pickers. I know I could use padding and margins, but I would like to keep this as much portable as I can.